# maximize window after timer finish

Tags: c#, timer, invoke

I would like to know how to maximize main form window after the timer was finished.

Assume that the window is minimize when the timer finished.

this is how I tried to implementing it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
  if (counter[int.Parse(timers[t].ToString())] <= 0)
                {
                    ReadyIndex = int.Parse(timers[t].ToString());

                   Invoke(new Action(() => {
                       this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                       this.Show();
                   }));

                    return;
                }
}
```

I tried also to do :

```
               Invoke(new Action(() => {
                   base.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                   base.Show();
               }));
```

and :

```
           Invoke(new Action(() => {
               thisForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
               thisForm.Show();
           }));
```

While "thisForm" is a Form1 variable and I initiate it in Form_Load method like this:

```
private Form1 thisForm;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                thisForm = new Form1();
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you make sure in the debugger that the line that is supposed to maximize the form is actually reached?

Comment: I didn't reach to Form1_SizeChanged, and I don't know why.

Comment: Then we cannot help you because there is not enough information here to find out. Debug the program. This is an essential skill.

Answer (score 0):

Make a public boolean called NowItsTime and set it to false.
When the timer starts make an if check to see if NowItsTime is true, and else statement if it's not.

If its true code:
 - Set the window state to maximized.
 - Stop the timer.

Else code:
 - Set NowItsTime to true.

Shortly explained:
It runs one time and stops straight on the next run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found the solution:

I used the first code but I switched between the Show() line and the windows change state(the code look like this):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
  if (counter[int.Parse(timers[t].ToString())] <= 0)
                {
                    ReadyIndex = int.Parse(timers[t].ToString());

                   Invoke(new Action(() => {
                       this.Show();
                       this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

                   }));

                    return;
                }
}
```

Maybe the way that the operation system mange the events are handling first the display and just after it changing the state.

Someone else has a better explanation?

Thanks for trying.